# Open a specific folder with explorer.exe

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a specific folder with explorer.exe and expect to get an error if the folder does not exist, but it simply opens a default folder instead.

Here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startArgs = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "explorer.exe", Arguments = Path.Combine(deskPath, "Room 1", "9am") };
try
{
    Process.Start(startArgs);
}
catch(exception ex) label1.Text = ex.Message; }
```

Comment: ProcessStartInfo startArgs = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "explorer.exe",
                    Arguments = Path.Combine(deskPath, "Room 1", "9am")
                };
                
                try
                {
                    Process.Start(startArgs);
                }
               catch(exception ex)
                    label1.Text = ex.Message;
                }

Comment: wait your comment? is that the code you have tried?

Comment: All you need is something like `if (Directory.Exists(dirPath)) Process.Start(dirPath);`

Comment: Thank you Ahmed I was looking way past the mark on that one. As a follow up, The path i want is on a network drive, so I know it is there and I want to read from it. If the path is not found it is because the network is asleep. How do I wake it up programatically?